# How can I use PHP to filter a list as though they had clicked on a Search Tool list item

Tags: development, mvc, jinput

Based on some internal conditions, I need to filter a list and have the "Search Tools" engaged showing the selected item in the filter list.  The net effect that we want is the same as appending the filter to the url like this `http:...&Itemid=161&filter[parent_id]=29`, which does *exactly* what I want.

According to [Setting and retrieving user state variables](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_user_state_variables#Setting_and_retrieving_the_variables):

> There are two ways to set user state variables. The first is fairly
>   intuitive, and is done using the JApplication::setUserState method.
>   The second is a little less obvious, and uses the
>   JApplication::getUserStateFromRequest method. There are also two ways
>   to retrieve user state variables. The first is using the
>   JApplication::getUserState method, and the second is to use the
>   JApplication::getUserStateFromRequest method.
>   JApplication::getUserStateFromRequest can be used to both store and
>   retrieve user state variables.

This is all fine for retrieving the information, but I'm unclear about the method and best place to SET a state variable to accomplish what the above URL does so that the value is saved where all the parts and pieces expected to find it along the way.

I've tried variations of this code in a number of places, and can usually get the output filtered, but unable to have the Search Tools displayed, so am apparently missing the part that sets up the values that `->getUserStateFromRequest` and other subsequent functions use.

```
// Load the filter state.
$search = $app->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context.'.filter.search', 'filter_search');
$this->setState('filter.search', preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $search));
```

The code has a loop like below - how do I "set" whatever `$app->getUserStateFromRequest` is going to "get" as the filters to loop through?

```
if ($filters = $app->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.filter', 'filter', array(), 'array')) {
    foreach ($filters as $name => $value) {
        $this->setState('filter.' . $name, $value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `display` method of your view class put this line before `parent::display($tpl);`:

```
$this->get('State')->filter = array('Foo'=>'Bar');
```

I always use this line to filter `featured` items in my components and it works:

```
$this->get('State')->{'filter.featured'} = 1;
```

Hope it helps.